# Does Apache or Nginx Proxy serve the browser caching directives?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, cache

I am running nginx as a proxy for my apache server. I am trying to leverage browser caching for PNG and JPG files. Which of these two should have the caching settings applied? I believe they both have the capability to do so, Apache via httpd.conf/htaccess, and nginx via nginx.conf Server section. Why one will the end user browser listen to? Both?

Comment: That's pretty redundant. You can improve performance much more significantly by using only one web server.

Comment: On typical setup where nginx and apache inside single server, nginx will become frontend. Nginx handle static file requests (image, js, css) and proxy the dynamic ones to apache. So the caching header of your image will be set by nginx.